# How to execute a function when an element is drag and dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable, javascript

I have a sorta-basic jquery/javascript question.

**The code below will create objects which can be dragged and dropped. If you click on an object, it will display the ID of the "next" object.**

**I wish to return this value (of the next object's ID) when the object is first "grabbed" (picked up without deliberately clicking) and then return the ID of the "next" object where it is placed.**

*Ideally, if the ID of the location it is grabbed is equal to the location where it is placed, it should not return any ID.*

The Jquery & Javascript

```
$(function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
});

$("li").live("click",function(e) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=($(this).next("li").attr('id'))
});
```

The CSS:

```
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#sortable li { margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; padding: 1px; float: left; width: 100px; height: 90px; font-size: 4em; text-align: center; }
</style>
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<ul id="sortable">
    <li id="li1" class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li id="li2" class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li id="li3" class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li id="li4" class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li id="li5" class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li id="li6" class="ui-state-default">6</li>
</ul>

</div>

<br><div id="result">Result Placed Here</div>
```

**I don't even know where to start because I do not know how to run the function without it being clicked (without grabbing).**

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Taylor

A JSfiddle can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/uuHsg/4/

Comment: You say that _"I wish to return this value (of the next object's ID) when the object is first grabbed"_ - what do you mean by the "next" object? The object currently being dragged, or the object that the currently-dragged object will be dropped onto? If it's the latter, your code will need to predict the future.

Comment: What is the purpose of making the `<li>`s sortable, but including a "Result placed here" area? It looks like you want the `<li>`s to be draggable _only_ onto the "Result placed here" area. Is that correct? If so, you don't want to use `sortable`.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I meant the result="id of next object".

If you drag the <li>'s and rearrange them, it will display the "next" <li> in that area

Comment: haha "your code will need to predict the future"! No i mean the "next" id of the <li> that is adjacent to it before it is dragged. So I click down will return this value, then when the user drops it into  a new location it will return the ID of the "next" li where it is placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [sortable events](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#events) `start` and `stop`.

```
$(function() {
    function startCallback(event, ui) {
        // stuff
    }

    function stopCallback(event, ui) {
        // other stuff
    }

    $("#sortable").sortable({
        start: startCallback,
        stop: stopCallback
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: One question..

   Using:
   ($(this).next("li").attr('id'));

It returns the value "Undefined". Is there any way to avoid this?